# Is there a word in Chinese to mean "mostly"? Is "大多" appropriate?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

As title， is there a word in Mandarin Chinese to mean "mostly" ? For example, I am going to tell my friend who wrote a letter to me that "I mostly got what you man", is it appropriate to say "大多" that I found in dictionary in this case for "mostly"?

Comment: Questions  are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not provide a bulk translation service.

Answer (score 3):

> is there a word in Mandarin Chinese to mean "mostly" ?

Of course, but that just depends on different kinds of senarios:

1) “相当，非常……”（程度副词）: adverb something related to the depth:

I **mostly** love peace (我**非常**热爱和平)

2）It's **mostly** bad=It's quite bad=It's awfully bad 糟糕**透**了！（implementation to describe "bad"'s depth in Chinese, but that's used as an adverb in English).

3）包含很大程度上的可能性，肯定：
**Mostly** speaking, It's almost of no hope to save people who sunk in the sea disaster of Korea.（可以这么说，救援韩国海难沉入水的群众希望破灭了）。

Answer (score 2):

You can use the phrase 大部分, which means "most of it". "I mostly get what you mean." can be translated to 你说的话我大部分都懂.